# (Udacity + GAE) Creating a form to edit existing ndb entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm starting my first small project with Google AppEngine (Python), tutored by Udacity. I've worked with Drupal.

I would like to create an "Edit" link in each job entity's page, which would allow its author to update the entity's fields. I'm not too sure where or how to begin achieving this. Any assistance would be very appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

main.py:

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import cgi
import urllib
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), 
                        autoescape = True)


def render_template(template, **params):
    t = env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)


# B A S E H A N D L E R #
#########################

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.write(*a, **kw)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.response.write(render_template(template, **kw))


# M A I N P A G E #
###################

class MainPage(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        jobs = Job.query()
        self.render('index.html', jobs = jobs)

# J O B   E N T I T Y #
#######################

class Job(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    requirements = ndb.TextProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class JobHandler(BaseHandler):
    pass
    # Created this empty class to organise its subclasses,
    # because they perform 'Job' functions.
    # Is this a good practice?

class NewJob(JobHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('newjob.html')

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        description = self.request.get('description')
        requirements = self.request.get('requirements')

        if title and description:
            j = Job(title = title, 
                    description = description, 
                    requirements = requirements)
            j.put()
            self.redirect('/job/%s' % str(j.key.id()))
        else:
            self.render('newjob.html')


class JobPage(JobHandler):

    def get(self, job_id):
        j = Job.get_by_id(int(job_id))
        self.render('jobpage.html', j = j)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/newjob', NewJob),
    ('/job/([0-9]+)', JobPage),
], debug=True)
```

The newpage.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<form method="post">

    <div>
        <label>Job Title:<br> 
            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{title}}">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Description:<br> 
            <textarea name="description" col="60">{{description}}</textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Requirements:<br> 
            <textarea name="requirements" col="60">{{requirements}}</textarea>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

And finally, the jobpage.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{j.title}}
    {{j.description}}
    {{j.requirement}}
    {{j.created.strftime("%b %d, %Y")}}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add an edit handler to your website. Something like ('/job/([0-9]+)/edit', EditJobPage) should do. After confirming the correct author is logged in, it could pull up the Job and place the values in text fields on a Get request. Then its Post function could accept the edited fields and update the Job accordingly.

You can then add this link directly to the Job html when its requested.

(Obviously this should only be done if the author is logged in)

```
<a href="/job/{{j.key.id()}}/edit}">
```

Make sure to confirm the author is logged in before allowing both the get and (more importantly) the post request to continue executing!

Edit:
 I didn't actually answer your question about how to edit existing ndb entities. The way that's done is by querying for the entity, reassigning a value to a an entity variable, and putting it.

```
job_to_edit = Job.get_by_id(job_id)  # or ndb.Key(Job, job_id).get()
job_to_edit.description = new_description
job_to_edit.put()
# Tada!
```

Disclaimer: My only experience is from taking this Udacity course.

Comment: Thank you yts. This makes sense. How would you get the job_number (of the job currently being viewed) from the URL using get()?

Comment: @haopei Welcome :) You'd get it the same way you get it in the get function of the JobPage handler. It'll be passed as the second parameter. Also, check my edited answer for how you could access the job number easily to stick into the html.

Comment: @haopei Thanks for accepting! Good luck with the course, I gained a lot from it.

Comment: thank _you_ for helping me through this. Extremely appreciative. 

I do have [a follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005657/assigning-an-author-to-an-entity-during-its-creation), if you are up for it :)