# Assigning an author to an entity during its creation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am doing Udacity's Web Dev Course with Google Appengine and Python.

I would like to know how I could assign to a created entity, its own *author*.

For example, I have two ndb.Models kinds:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    bio = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class Blog(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    body = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

When a *Blog* entity is created by a logged-in user, its own author (*User* entity) should also be identified with it.

Ultimately, I would like to display a blog's post with its author's information (for example, the author's *bio*)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Blog` class should include a property to store the key of the user who wrote it:

```
author = ndb.KeyProperty(required = True)
```

You can then set this property when you create a Blog instance:

```
blog = Blog(title="title", body="body", author=user.key)
```

For optimization, if you know the logged in user's ndb.Key, and you don't need the user entity itself, you would pass that directly, instead of needing to fetch the user first.

```
assert isinstance(user_key, ndb.Key)
blog = Blog(title="title", body="body", author=user_key)
```

In full:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class Blog(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    body = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    author = ndb.KeyProperty(required = True)

def new_blog(author):
    """Creates a new blog post for the given author, which may be a ndb.Key or User instance"""
    if isinstance(author, User):
        author_key = author.key
    elif isinstance(author, ndb.Key):
        assert author.kind() == User._get_kind()  # verifies the provided ndb.Key is the correct kind.
        author_key = author

    blog = Blog(title="title", body="body", author=author_key)
    return blog
```

You may get *bonus points* if you standardize the beginning of new_blog to a utility function.

Comment: Thank you @Josh. I think I've got it! Follow up question: Is it the best way to store the author as a _KeyProperty_? In this situation, what are advantages of using _KeyProperty_ over _StringProperty_?

Comment: You'll want to use a `KeyProperty` if you want the author's name to have the ability to change. You can fetch the author with `author = blog.author.get()` and then the username with `author.username` - if you want to condense to one line, you have `blog.author.get().username`, but you'll ideally want to keep the author reference.

Comment: I've just come across the `ReferenceProperty` property, and it seems to be very similar to the solution described here. Is there any reason to use the KeyProperty over the ReferenceProperty in a situation such as this?

Comment: ReferenceProperty is specific to db (not `ndb`, which is what you are using). ReferenceProperty's have been more or less deprecated, and I've found in my experience that it's easier to avoid them in the long run (for optimization). It's better to understand exactly when your code is pulling from the datastore, and ReferenceProperty's obfuscated that functionality.